# Deploy application on cloud, choosing a machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to develop a training platform with video content and start implemententing it using spring boot as the framework for the backend server and mysql as storage. When a new video is saved, I save it on the file system and I maintain the reference in the database. I need to put the application in cloud and I don't know how to choose the proper machine for this type of application, can you help me?

Thanks.